# Substract color from all objects to mode alpha

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, svg, color-theory

I am trying to make some stuff from Illustrator, with using remove once color to setting up alpha mode.

I created example from Photoshop like that:

[image]

Any Idea?

**Edit 1:** Recolor Art is useless, no option for mode alpha.

**Edit 2:** Must be any algorithm, if one object is full filled with one white, then this object will be 100% transperency. If other object is filled with combined 1/2 white and 1/2 blue color then 100% blue and 50% transperency...

Comment: Illustrator does not have a equivalent function. The same effect can be done but it will be painfull, unless you know how to script. In which case its not such a big deal. But still substantially bigger investment.

Comment: Oh, right. May other tool SVG or plugin/script for AI can make it like that? What by name is this exact function?

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen a vector app capable of what you are seeking other than using something like the Multiply blend mode.

Comment: Not multiply and not blend mode too, objects must be transperent. ;)

Comment: Then what you are asking is impossible for vector apps in my experience.

Comment: Soon I'll show you my right. I am gonna to build scirpt.

Comment: @Scott: Imposibble? Anything is possible. :)

Answer (score -1):

I did script, now i have possible for copying colors to setup new gradient and transperency from reading on raster image. Programmatically can use all points of vector image to set new colors.

[image: result of transperency objects]

But that's not all ..I had a lot of errors in locating them on a raster image, you need to know well on math. These images are not the same because of the inaccuracy location.

Somehow color subtraction can be calculated with the eraser technique used in photoshop as I used at work. I don't know how to.

Comment: Can you share the script? Your post isn't really considered an answer without it